# Laravel eloquent get most common value in a database column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

From a table `animals` I have the following values in the `animal_name` column

`cat
 dog
 cat`

I want to pull the word cat from that because it is the most popular/common word in that column. How do I do that using laravel eloquent?

Comment: what do u mean by pull the word? , do  you mean counting the most common value?

Comment: $animals->countBy('column');

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Eloquent:

```php
App\Animal::select('name')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
```

Output:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#711
     all: [
       App\Animal {#725
         name: "cat",
       },
     ],
   }
```

---

Same thing with Query Builder:

```php
DB::table('animals')
    ->select('name')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
```

Output:

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#734
     all: [
       {#738
         +"name": "cat",
       },
     ],
   }
```

---

> Any way to also fetch the "cat" count in the same query?

Sure there is

```
App\Animal::select('name')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS count')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->orderByDesc('count')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
```

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#711
     all: [
       App\Animal {#725
         name: "cat",
         count: 123
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! Any way to also fetch the "cat" count in the same query?

Comment: I wish I could upvote the second time now. Thanks :).

How do you figure these out? I know MySQL, and I know a bit of Laravel, but mixing them together seems like a mystery whenever I need some custom piece of logic.

Comment: You can also use `first()` instead of `limit(1)->get()`

Comment: how to extract cat as a string instead of laravel object..