# Laravel: get the most used words with eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table post and it have a column content. The content column is text. I want to get the most used words in content today with eloquent

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: is it laravel 5 or greater?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894294/laravel-eloquent-get-most-common-value-in-a-database-column

Comment: Is the `content` column like the body of the `post` and you want to grab all the text in all the content columns and grab the most used out of all of them?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, assuming table name = `post` and field name = `content`:

```
$mostUsed = Post::take(1)
    ->groupBy('content')
    ->orderBy('content', 'desc')
    ->count('content');
```

Will get the **first** most common `content` in the table, and:

```
$mostUsed = Post::groupBy('content')
    ->orderBy('content', 'desc')
    ->count('content');
```

Will get the registers ordered from the most common to the most rare. By the way, this is just an adaption from MySQL to Eloquent according to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693626/2414842)

Comment: thanks, please and if i want to get only the #htags?

Comment: what is "htags"?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is this.

**NOTE**: since you have not provided any table structure, I don't know how to filter today's posts. I hope there is a column named `date`.

Count all the words that has used today.

```
// array of all the content strings.
$contents = Post::where('date', date('Y-m-d'))->pluck('content');

// final result will be stored here as a key value pair.
// used count against each word.
$word_count = [];

foreach($contents as $content) {

    // array of each word in the content separated by 'space'.
    $words = explode(' ', $content);

    foreach($words as $word) {

        // if the word has already used +1 the count, else set the count as 1.
        $count = array_key_exists($word, $word_count) ? ($word_count[$word] + 1) : 1;

        // set new word count to the array.
        array_set($word_count, $word, $count);
    }
}

$most_used_word = array_search(max($word_count), $word_count);
```